# Custom marker in VichGeographicalBundle and Symfony2

Tags: google-maps-api-3, symfony-2.1

How do I set a custom marker in symfony2 and [VichGeographicalBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichGeographicalBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)?

My map file constructor:

```
 public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $iconGenerator)
{
    parent::__construct();

    // configure your map in the constructor 
    // by setting the options

    $this->setShowZoomControl(true);
    $this->setZoom(15);
    $this->setAutoZoom(false);
    $this->setContainerId('map_canvas');
    $this->setWidth(630);
    $this->setHeight(200);
}
```

My twig call:

```
{{ vichgeo_map_for('showShop',shop) }}
```

Everything works ok, except the marker which I cannot find how to set it to a custom image (image/custom.png).

I tried to inject a service in config.yml but my knowledge is too poor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use clustering in VichGeographicalBundle for Symfony2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214127/how-can-i-use-clustering-in-vichgeographicalbundle-for-symfony2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<?php

namespace YourBundle\Map\Marker\Icon;

use Vich\GeographicalBundle\Map\Marker\Icon\IconGeneratorInterface;
use ..\Shop; // set the correct path

class CustomDefaultIconGenerator implements IconGeneratorInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function generateIcon($obj)
    {
        if ($obj instanceof Shop) {
            return '/images/custom.gif'; // make sure the path is correct
        }
    }
}
```

And in your configs:

```
services:
    ...
    vich_geographical.icon_generator.default:
        class: YourBundle\Map\Marker\Icon\CustomDefaultIconGenerator
        public: false
```

But it looks like marker support is a bit incomplete in the bundle. There must be a better way to do it ;)